# Chrome extension OAuth2 select account (doesn't work)

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-signin, browser-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension, still on manifest V2. I use Google OAuth 2.0 API to authenticate the user. The auth url goes like this:

> ```
> "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
> client_id: "511686366022-svms8eqloddqu73vobnqqc7nrk34i68o.apps.googleusercontent.com"
> redirect_uri: "https://{extension id}.chromiumapp.org"
> response_type: "code"
> scope: "profile email"
> access_type: "offline"
> prompt: "select_account"
> ```

The problem is I can't get `prompt: "select_account"` to work! So I get a popup like this:
[image]

**What did I miss? I there certain permissions required or something?**